# Getting 500 server error from Ajax call to a SOAP web method in .Net

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, ajax, soap

I have two different async calls I am doing with ajax. Both are done the same way, but the one has parameters for the web method. The link is correct, when I follow it I get the return correctly in the browser, but I just keep getting a server 500 error. Any ideas?
The one works fine without parameters, here is the JS/jQuery code since I am slightly sure it isn't on the C# side:

```
function CatChanged() {
    var strA = $('#ddlCategory').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: encodeURI('https://localhost:44380/WebService1.asmx/GetProducts?category=' + strA),
        data: '<soap: Envelope xmlns: xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns: xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns: soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/%22%3E<soap: Body><xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" /></soap: Body></soap: Envelope >',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "text/xml",
        dataType: "text/xml",
        success: function (response) {
           alert(response.responseText);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert("ERROR!!");
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the web method code from the C# code behind:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    [ScriptService]
    public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string GetCategories()
        {
            Catalog cat = new Catalog();
            JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            return jss.Serialize(cat.categories);
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public string GetProducts(string category)
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            Catalog cat = new Catalog();
            List<string> retList = new List<string>();
            switch (category)
            {
                case "Electronics":
                    foreach (Product product in cat.electronicProducts)
                    {
                        retList.Add(product.itemName);
                    }
                    return jss.Serialize(retList);
                case "Apparel":
                    foreach (Product product in cat.apparelProducts)
                    {
                        retList.Add(product.itemName);
                    }
                    return jss.Serialize(retList);
                case "Food and Drink":
                    foreach (Product product in cat.electronicProducts)
                    {
                        retList.Add(product.itemName);
                    }
                    return jss.Serialize(retList);
                default:
                    foreach (Product product in cat.electronicProducts)
                    {
                        retList.Add(product.itemName);
                    }
                    return jss.Serialize(retList);
            }
        }
```

...
Here is a screenshot of the return I get in the browser when I follow the direct link from the developer's console in Chrome:
[image]

The return is all good from the web method when called from the url. In which leads me to think that it has to be something in the ajax call, and i'm not sure what I need to do different in order to consume it when I add the parameter to the web method. Like I said, the first web method works in my JavaScript code, and I was able to parse everything from the return just fine.

Also, using any other services, MVC, or anything like that isn't an option. I have to make it work given the current situation.

Answer (score 1):

Alright so if i understand you correctly. When you visit the URL with your browser the results work just fine. But when you do an ajax call you're having troubles.

The one thing i noticed from your code is that you're doing a POST request with your ajax call but the methodes are both GET. Try changing the type within your ajax call to GET.

E.g.

```
function CatChanged() {
    var strA = $('#ddlCategory').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: encodeURI('https://localhost:44380/WebService1.asmx/GetProducts?category=' + strA),
        data: '<soap: Envelope xmlns: xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns: xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns: soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/%22%3E<soap: Body><xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" /></soap: Body></soap: Envelope >',
        type: 'GET', // <-- Changed from POST to GET
        contentType: "text/xml",
        dataType: "text/xml",
        success: function (response) {
           alert(response.responseText);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert("ERROR!!");
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, I had changed all of that a hundred times it seems since I started trying to debug. I'll update my question with what I get back from trying the GET again, if I still am having trouble. Thanks!!